# Problem with TransformedDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am trying to use Mathematica to obtain the probability distribution of $\frac{1}{2}(A + B)$ where $A$ and $B$ are independent random variables each distributed according to the uniform distribution, with lower and upper bounds of $L$ and $H$ respectively.

I suspect the distribution is triangular with lower and upper bounds of $L$ and $H$ respectively and mode equal to $\frac{1}{2}(A + B)$. However, I am having difficulty using TransformedDistribution to show that.

My code is:

```
\[ScriptCapitalD] = TransformedDistribution[1/2 (A + B), {B \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{L, H}], A \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{L, H}]}]
```

Comment: That was a typo. But I am still not getting what I expect.

Comment: Did you try `PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD], y]`?

Comment: PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD], y] produces one expression with a denominator that looks correct, but the triangular distribution is split at the mode. Mathematica is not showing that. At least not in a way that is easy to see.

Comment: Are you aware `TriangularDistribution[]` is built-in?

Comment: @ J. M. is slightly pensive Yes, I am aware of that. I guess I was expecting Mathematica to confirm I am dealing with a triagular distribution as it does nicely when (A + B) is not multipled by 0.5.

Comment: Why not check the PDFs? `Simplify[PDF[TransformedDistribution[(a + b)/2, {a, b} \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{{l, h}, {l, h}}]], t] == PDF[TriangularDistribution[{l, h}], t], l < t < h]`

Comment: That's basically all I was looking for.

Comment: I think I have found a bug! Try the following two expressions. The only difference is that I use U in one and H in the other for the upper limit.


`Simplify[PDF[TransformedDistribution[(A + B)/2, {A, B} \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{{L, U}, {L, U}}]], t] == PDF[TriangularDistribution[{L, U}], t], L < t < U]`

and 


`Simplify[PDF[TransformedDistribution[(A + B)/2, {A, B} \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{{L, H}, {L, H}}]], t] == PDF[TriangularDistribution[{L, H}], t], L < t < H]`

Comment: @user120911 It does look like a bug to me. I think you should report it to WRI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get what you expect if you do it it in two steps

```
\[ScriptCapitalD] = 
 TransformedDistribution[x/2, 
  x \[Distributed] TransformedDistribution[(A + B), {
     B \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{L, H}],
     A \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{L, H}]}]]

(* TriangularDistribution[{L, H}] *)
```

Comment: That is very nice!

Answer (score 3):

```
PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]][z]
```

> (((-30 + z)*Sign[-30 + z])/2 - (-20 + z)*
>       Sign[-20 + z] + ((-10 + z)*Sign[-10 + z])/2)/100

For plotting, assign values to `L` and `H`:

```
L = 10; H = 30;
Plot[Evaluate@PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]][x], {x, 10, 30}]
```

[image]

```
pdF[l_, h_] := Module[{L = l, H = h}, Evaluate[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]]]]
Plot[Evaluate @ Flatten@Table[pdF[l, h][x], {l, {0, 5}}, {h, {10, 15}}], {x, 0, 15},
  PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> (Flatten @ Table[ToString@{l, h}, {l, {0, 5}}, {h, {10, 15}}])]
```

[image]

Comment: That confirms my intution, but can you get Mathematica to output the PDF for the triangular distribution? That is what I am having trouble doing.